# How to keep precision while dividing

Tags: java

I currently am dividing 2 numbers and trying to keep precision but not working:

```
BigDecimal percent = bgd1.divide(bgd2, new MathContext(3, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN)).multiply(new BigDecimal(100));
```

produces results:

**24.200**,
**3.000**,
**63.100**

How can I keep precision to 3 decimals so my results are like the following:

**27.241**,
**3.019**,
**63.172**

instead.

Comment: You have defined in your division that it should use a precision of 3, so it will at most give you 3 decimal places like Y.XXX. If you then multiply that by 100 you will obviously end up with YXX.X and only 1 decimal place. Either use more precision in your division or change the order of your operations (multiply by 100 first, divide after that)

Comment: With your specific example, multiply before you devide. In general, use a RoundingMode adapted to your needs. The one you specify in your code is the direct cause of your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help, not sure what you mean.

Comment: Your code explicitely produce a first number rounded down to three digits through division with your `new MathContext(3, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN)`. Then there's no surprise the following number can't restore the lost precision. Either do the multiplication first, and your division will produce the target number with the correct precision, or remove that `MathContext` from your first operation and only put it on the last.